# How a client can request two different scopes depending on the user ?Does it make sense? Open Id Connect // Identity Server 4

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver4, openid-connect, policy

I am trying to full understand what OpenId Connect can provide, and how.

I will enumerate the doubts so you could answer them in order.

**A)** Context: Imagine there is a protected resource "Phone.Api" with following scopes :"scope.admin", "scope.read" and "scope.write". We access it using a MVC web-based client called "phone.Client"

**a.1)** Imagine "Supermaster Billy" and "Standard Jean" are using both the same client. How could I manage to get "scope.admin" for Billy and "scope.read" for jean if they are using same client?

**a.2)** Should "phone.Client" add every scope in the request of an access_token ?Cause when I define the authentication parameters in my client ,I have to define the scopes that will be requested to the user.

```
services.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
   options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
   options.Authority = "http://localhost:4000";
   options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
   options.ClientId = "phone.client";
   options.ClientSecret = "secret";
   options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
   options.Scope.Add("scope.admin"); //here I should request all scopes?? what happens if I don`t want Jean to have scope.admin ?
   options.Scope.Add("scope.read");
   options.Scope.Add("scope.write");
   options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
   options.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

I don´t get how I could get ask different scopes (inside access_token) using same client.

**a3)** Imagine client, allways request all the scopes it has available. That might be correct since it is what client is allowed to do despite the user permissions inside app.  Is this correct?

**B)** Open Id connect , when states that it provides authentication and authorization it is talking about. Which  of my assumptions are correct?

**b1)** Authenticating user in a centralized way (using a centralized identity provider)

**b2)** Users authorize Clients to access protected resources in his behalf?

**b3)** Server authorize clients to access to proyected resources

Many thanks!!

Comment: Read the answers and comments of your previous question. It's all there.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg i have still these doubts. Please answer them if you can

Comment: are you using asp.net identity with IdentityServer  ?

Answer (score 0):

I think something important to note here is that the identity provider you are trying to login with determines what your user may or may not access.

For example if you request a api scope you are asking the identity provider to access their api on behalf of the user. When the user logs in with the identity provider the identity provider checks the scopes and will check if the user may access the api.

For passing security groups most of the times a scope groups can be requested. If this scope is provided the identity provider will provide you with claims over the groups the user belongs to

[Scopes provided by identity provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEh0k.png)

Answer (score 0):

- **identityserver** mainly for Authenticating
- use **policyserver.local**  for Authorization
- **policyserver.local** and **identityserver** is form the same team
- This talk is **must see** , it's where they announce policyserver.local and how to use it

  - [Authorization is hard! Implementing Authorization in Web Applications and APIs - Brock Allen & Dominick Baier on Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/254635640)